# Access ng-if value from Cypress

Tags: angularjs, cypress

I am pretty new to AngularJS and Cypress and I have been looking around on resolving this issue with no success.

I have a section with an ng-if

```
<section ng-if="!hasKey">
```

and I would like to get this hasKey value to determine if I should execute one extra step in a Cypress test to do something like this:

```
if(hasKey) {        
    cy.someFunc();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the existence of the `section` element give you that value?

Comment: May I suggest you switch to Angular (non-js) if you can. Also if you are setting up the test, I would think you would know if that key is there. I am not trying to be snarky but your test case might be that the section is there, test for it. I am trying to understand how your test case changes from run to run, that sometimes the key is there and sometimes the key is not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Maccurt, we are planning to start switching to Angular soon. The problem here is that I want to do some more stuff is the section is not there, therefore I can't just do a get on that section because the test would fail (Correct me if I am wrong) And that's why Richard's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may suffice to infer `hasKey` value from the presence of the element, like this

```
cy.get('section').then(_ => {
  cy.someFunc()
})
```

but if you want to test more explicitly, please see this blog [Control an AngularJS Application From E2E Tests to get access to properties on the angularjs scope](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/15/control-angular-application-from-e2e-tests/#Element-scope) to get at the internal properties of your AngularJs app.

```
const getAngular = () =>
  cy.window()
    .its('angular')

const getElementScope = (selector) =>
  cy.get(selector)
    .then($el =>
      getAngular()
        .then(ng => ng.element($el).scope())
    )

it('has hasKey property in scope', () => {
  getElementScope('section')
    .its('hasKey').then(hasKey => {
      if(hasKey) {        
        cy.someFunc();
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Your example and the reference helped me achieve what I was looking for